# Flutter - Auth token & refresh token workflow

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, jwt

I'm searching for simple tutorials or examples for Flutter authentication using, authentication token and refresh token workflow using JWT. (How to make Login with auth token and refresh token)

I'm using Node.js for the backend and JWT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just generate the token using the jsonwebtoken npm library. You can also adjust the expiry time of the token (refer to the documentation of the library). After the token is generated persist the token to the client (in your case flutter app) then save the token in the local device, you can use shared preference library of flutter to store key value pairs in local storage of device.Using this token you can make simpe login and logout system and also authentcate all your requesta to server.